# How to allow users who don't accept a permsToRequestOnConnect : publish_stream

Tags: facebook

I use FB connect and have a permsToRequestOnConnect : publish_stream set.  I'd like to grant users access to the site even if they click "Don't allow", but this doesn't seem to work.  I'm using Facebooker with Authlogic, and when users hit "Don't allow" it just doesn't log in and stays on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a facebook expert, but I believe you need to go thru the FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog api instead, and manually capture the return values and do something about it.